# Evaluating non Node-based Xpath expression(count()) using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, xpath

I need to figure out a way to evaluate a count Xpath expression in C# .net.  Currently I am looping through an XML document, and I end up on a particular node.  I need to figure out which node that I am on at that point.  The node is differentiated by an attribute that has a value.

```
    <A>
     <B>
      <C> 
       <D attr="10"/>
      </C>
      <C> 
       <D attr="10"/>
      </C>
      <C> 
       <D attr="11"/>
      </C>
      <C> 
       <D attr="10"/><!--Imagine I am here...  This would be the 3rd D attr that equals 10-->
      </C>
      <C> 
       <D attr="12"/>
      </C>
     </B>
    </A>
```

Let's say I am on the second
I currently have an XMLDocument open. And I have selected a list of nodes... I am worried that If I open an XpathDocument I will lose my position in the xmlNode list.  I guess I could get the attr value by using xpath and then use an XpathDocument and Evaluate that expression that way.  I was hoping there might be an easier way.

thanks.

Comment: You should share the relevant C# code as well. Answering your question would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(int) (theDocument.CreateNavigator()
        .Evaluate("count(/A/B/C[D/@attr = 10][3]/preceding-sibling::C) +1"))
```

On the provided XML document the result is:

```
4
```